# statistical analysis of two data sets have different number of sampling

Tags: dataset, statistics, data, bigdata, sampling

I have two datasets from my statistical fault analysis: one with 400 iterations and another with 500 iterations. Both datasets have the same maximum and minimum values, and some data points are identical. I am seeking advice on how to compare these datasets and calculate the relative difference (error percentage) for each data point.